# Need advice on application architecture

Tags: java, apache-flex, tomcat, architecture, blazeds

Being a new user I could not post images. I have described my problem in the image at
http://riverstreamweb.com/URLWathcerArchitecture.png

Please check out the link and share your opinion/suggestions

Thanks!

Comment: Aside from being unclear what your question actually is, this seems quite too complicated for a simple notification service... Why aren't you just using some Comet implementation?

Comment: @Viruzzo Yes, it indeed is a simple notification service. The key requirement here is to have the Monitor Service running independently and NOT be tied up with a particular session. It needs to be global. Unfortunately, comet implementation cannot be used since i have to use blazeds which do not yet support comet style connections. Thanks!

Comment: I hoped that describing the requirment in an image [link](http://riverstreamweb.com/URLWathcerArchitecture.png) would make it easy :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/LiveCycleDataServicesES/3.1/Developing/WS9d22440892c78ffa-3a437432122a8558cdf-8000Update.html

You can simply add a JDBC poller that monitors your database inside the FeedThread run method.

Comment: Thanks for that link Peter, it seems to be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome.  You can tick off the answer if it's good enough :)